# Column of BindingSource with Anonymous Class as DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, linq, data-binding, anonymous-class

Is there any method to select a column of the current row of a BindingSource whose DataSource is an anonymous class?

```
var userResults = from u in dataContext.Users
          join c in dataContext.Computers on u.ID equals c.UserID
          where doSearch
             && u.Name.Contains(userNameTextBox.Text)
             && u.UserName.Contains(userUsernameTextBox.Text)
          select new { u.Name, u.UserName, u.Branch, c.Installations, u.ID };
userBindingSource.DataSource = userResults;
```

I want to get the current value of `u.ID`.

Comment: You binding source is bound to which type of control?

Comment: It's bound to a DataGridView control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that items in the BindingSource are of type Object and you need to convert them back to their anonymous type, and you can't do that.... actually, [you can](http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx) (check the "Casting to anonymous types" section), but it's a clever trick that might not work in the future.

Other (better) options to get the value of a property:

- Use a concrete type instead of an anonymous type
- Use reflection to get the value of the property
- C# 4.0 only: Use the dynamic keyword then call the property you need
- Get the value in the bound control (for example, if your datasource is bound to a DataGridView, get the value of the datagridview cell instead of the binding source value)

Comment: But how does the .NET Framework solve this problem? If I want to bind another BindingSource to a sub-list of my current one, I just have to set the string property `DataMember`, how is this member variable resolved from the (maybe anonymous) DataSource object?

Comment: From what I could find, I think it uses reflection to find the bound property's value.